# What are the most important aspects to look into when building an experimental sounding rocket?

Tags: rockets, sounding-rocket

I have broken down the process plan to various subsystems( including a Recovery system)but would want to know from the community what are the most important aspects of the rocket that one must focus on...

Answer (score 3):

This is getting close-votes for being opinion-based, but I guess most people here will agree about two primary things; both "number one" because neglecting either is the end of the project. Law, and safety.

1. Law. Countries have different regulations regarding rocketry, starting from complete ban, through necessity to be a member of a registered organization, get permit for any launches and tests, and so on. There is very little technical difference between a sounding rocket and a missile, so building one without proper permits can very easily get qualified as terrorist activity.

.

1. Safety. I'd recommend the lecture of [Ignition](https://library.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf) on how that kind of work goes. Accidents happen, and will happen. If by the end of your project you still have your eyebrows and all the fingers, count yourself lucky. Regardless, safety should be a priority, because with meticulous safety accidents will be rare and not likely to be serious. With anything less... say good-bye to your fingers.

Answer (score 2):

### **SAFETY**

Rockets are dangerous.  Rockets that are big and go high are very dangerous.  You can easily kill yourself or others.

Comment: Counterpoint: the safest rocket is one that doesn't fly, and it's surprisingly easy to impose so many safety features on a vehicle as to render it incapable of actually accomplishing its intended mission.

Comment: @Tristan True.  I wonder if that actually happens for amateur rocket projects, though.

Comment: As long as the amateur rocketeers have some degree of sanity, restricting their original work to the overall vehicle and sticking with COTS propulsion (which can get you a very long way these days), it becomes merely a matter of practicing proper range safety.  Protip: don't try to make your own motors/engines unless you already do this professionally and know very well what you are doing.